# I am having a problem with bcrypt compare. I succed to hash password on Register page, but I not to compare successfully on login page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, compare, bcrypt

Here is Register form where I get the hashed password:

```
getAllUsers().then((res) => {
      let user = res.data.find(
        (u) => u.ugovor === ugovor 
      );

      if (user) {
        setUser(user) {
 
        bcrypt.genSalt(10, (err, salt)=> {
          bcrypt.hash(user.password, salt, (err, hash) => {
            
            postUser(user.id, hash, password, email).then((res) => {
              user = res.data;
              setPassword(prev => [...prev, hash]);
              //loggedIn.password = hash;
              setEmail(prev => [...prev, user]);
              history("/login");
              setError("");
              console.log("uspesna registracija");
            })
          })
        }) 
      } else {
        setError("Не постоји купац са унесеним бројем Уговора и мерила");
        return 0;
      }
    });
  }}>
```

And here is LogIn form, everything works but compare hashed password, if I compare inputed and hashed password directly compare is also false:

```
getAllUsers().then((res) => {
     
      let user = res.data.find(
        
        (u) => u.ugovor === ugovor 
      );
       const doesPasswordMatch = bcrypt.compareSync(password, user.password); 
       if(!doesPasswordMatch) {
         console.log('compare not success');
         return 0;
}           else {
        
        console.log('compare success')
}
        if (user) {
      
        setLogIn(true);
        setUser(user);
        history("/profile");
        console.log("uspesno ulogovan");
       
      } else {
        setError("Broj Ugovora i lozinka se ne podudaraju");
      }   

    });
  }}
```

I tried compare, compareSync, with await, even this, but nothing works, it wont recognise hashed password:

```
bcrypt.compare(password, user.password, function(err, result) {
// result == true
});
```

Comment: Surely if you are using bcrypt you are also not storing plaintext passwords. How do you expect `u.password === password` to work?

Comment: Yeah, I made a mistake copying the code,  && u.password === password is commented, I really dont know what should be a problem. Thanks for the respoonse eather way

Answer (score 0):

Try this for your login. Please, remember to give some feed up.

```
getAllUsers().then((res) => {
 // look for user
 let user = res.data.find((u) => u.ugovor === ugovor);

 if (user) {
  // user is found
  const hashedPassword = u.password; // get stored hashed password
  // compare passwords
  const doesPasswordMatch = bcrypt.compareSync(password, hashedPassword, (err, result) => {
    if (err) console.log(err);
     // result == true
    });

  if (doesPasswordMatch) {
   // correct password
   console.log("compare success");
   setLogIn(true);
   setUser(user);
   history("/profile");
   console.log("uspesno ulogovan");
  } else {
   // wrong password
   console.log("compare not success");
   return 0;
  }
} else {
 // user is not found
 setError("Broj Ugovora i lozinka se ne podudaraju");
}
```

});

Comment: Thanks for the response, I've tried this already, and somehow comparing is always false, I am getting "compare not success" . My code is the same as yours but this part:  hashedPassword = user.password

Comment: If that's the case, then you're in the block of user found but wrong password, which means you're either typing the wrong password or it's not hashed at all. You have "loggedIn" in your code. I don't see where that's coming from. Shouldn't it be "user" instead?

Comment: I have replaced the loggedIn  with user earlier as well. I am getting hashed password in my db, and I am sure that typed password is correct. Even when I copy hashed password and enter it in input field I dont get compare success... :/